# Using $geoWithin issue mongoid

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid, nosql

Any means currently built out in Mongoid to use `$geoWithin` without storing anything in the db?

Wanting to be able to just use `$geoWithin` (or another similar method) by just calling it on some object that has the coordinates and subsequently passing the polygonal boundaries.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Have you used geo_near?

This worked for me

```
center = [lat.to_f, lon.to_f]
User.geo_near(center).max_distance(10)
```

User model definition:

```
field :location, type:Array  # [lat,lng]
index( { location: "2d" }, { min: -180, max: 180 })
```